# Setting django timezone on runtime

Tags: python, django

While I have a default timezone of UTC in my settings file, occasionally I need to overwrite this timezone. Without using something like `pytz` is it possible to set the `tza` at runtime. For example:

```
from django.utils import timezone
tz = 'America/New_York' 
now = timezone(tz).now() # in pseudocode
```

Would there be a way to accomplish the above?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `activate` method here:

```
from django.utils import timezone
tz = 'America/New_York' 
timezone.activate(pytz.timezone(tz))
now = timezone.now()
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/timezones/

Comment: FWIW `timezone.now()` will always return a UTC aware datetime even when a different timezone is activated. The sole purpose of `timezone.activate` is to control the timezone used to render value.

Answer (score 1):

Your settings' timezone is the `default time zone` but according to **[Default time zone and current time zone](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/timezones/#default-time-zone-and-current-time-zone)** you can use the `current time zone` with **.activate()**.

Hope it helps. :)